# How to print a count in Collections.forEach()

Tags: java, java-8

So I've got a list as follows, with the lambda expression:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
...
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
array.stream().forEach((item) -> {
    buf.append("Counter here: " + item.toString() + "\n");
});
return buf.toString();
```

But i can't instantiate and modify a variable within the `forEach` lambda expression because it has to be `final`. Is there a way i can do this?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want the index of each element?

Comment: Yeah or just a counter like '0: ...' and '1: ...'

Comment: MutableInteger is available in apache-lang that has less overhead than AtomicInteger.  Also avoid using StringBuffer as a local variable use StringBuilder (StringBuffer is synchronized and StringBuilder is not, unless you are going to update that buffer with multiple threads you are incurring the extra cost without benefit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use atomics for this:

```
AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger(0);
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("");
array.stream().forEach((item) -> {
    buf.append("Counter here: " + cnt.incrementAndGet() + "\n");
});
return buf.toString();
```

Comment: Wouldnt this code throw error for making `buf` `final` or _effectively final_ ??

Comment: @LalitRao `cnt` and `buf` are effectively final, no error here. It'll work fine on Java 8.

Comment: Would u please explain me this in detail?
I mean we are mutating the state of `buf` inside lambda right?
So how it remains effectively final then ?

Comment: @LalitRao In few words: you're allowed to modify internal state of the objects you're referencing from lambda expression. But you're not allowed to change the object references themself, e.g. `buf.toString()` and `cnt.incrementAndGet()` are allowed but `buf = buf.append("test")` or for example `i = i + 1`, `i++` are not

Comment: Thanks mate :) Well explained

Answer (score 0):

Use an `int[]` of size 1 for the counter:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
int[] count = {0};
return array.stream().map(item -> count[0]++ + ":" + item)
  .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "", "\n"));
```

The `int[]` is effectively final. It's *contents* don't have to be.

Note how you don't even need the `StringBuilder` if you use the `joining()` collector.

Comment: `<thinks-to-self>`I wish there was a feature that allowed folks to mark the place in the answer that is "not useful" when downvoting`</thinks-to-self>`

Comment: `<thinks-out-loud>` I wish moderators and Java gold badge holders could vote to close duplicates appropriately.`</thinks-out-loud>`

Comment: @Pillar hmmm, well this answer isn't in the dupe, but ok....

Comment: Isn’t the policy to add the answer there instead of not closing a dupe question? Anyway, you should consider that there might be a good reason for such an answer not being there…